# Difference between write method in javaScript

Tags: javascript, methods

What is the difference between "Document.Write()" and "document.write()" method in JavaScript programming language.

Comment: WTF? There's no `Document.Write()`.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `Document` is different to `document`. `Document.Write()` should throw something along the lines of "undefined is not a function", as there is no `Write` method on `Document`.